# SecurityException at starting intent of a new empty Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-activity

I have developed a little project using just one Activity, and now, I'm trying to add a new one, but, I recieve this error when I'm trying to launch the project on my device:

> Running com.android.gl2jni/.TestActivity... 1>  Starting: Intent {
>   cmp=com.android.gl2jni/.TestActivity } 1>   1> 
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {
>   flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.gl2jni/.TestActivity } from null
>   (pid=2935, uid=2000) requires null

I'm not trying to call the new Activity, and I have developed an empty Activity to check why I can't launch the app.

This is my Manisfest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.gl2jni">


  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"/>

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

  <application
          android:label="@string/gl2jni_activity">

    <!--main activity-->

    <activity android:name=".GL2JNIActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!--BT device list activity-->

    <activity android:name=".TestActivity"
              >
      <intent-filter>
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <!--
      <activity android:name=".BluetoothDeviceListActivity"
                  android:label="@string/select_device"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" 
                          android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  />
    -->

  </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is the empty activity class:

```
package com.android.gl2jni;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        LogConsole.print( "HI, I AM TestActivity" );
    }

}
```

I suppose that I have to modify something else more, but I don't know what...
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You've specified an empty intent filter for TestActivity. An empty intent filter matches NO intents. Remove these lines from the  block for TestActivity:

```
  <intent-filter>
  </intent-filter>
```

Also, in `onCreate()` of `TestActivity` you must call `super.onCreate()`, otherwise Android will crash it.